# Searching the same line in different arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I have six different arrays each with the same amount of elements in them, my question is, if I want to view the line that says 'test' and it happens to be the 22nd line, is there a way so that I can view the 22nd of all the arrays at the same time and then print them to the console, is it possible to do that?

e.g. I want to search through one array and then when it finds 'test' it prints out the same index of all arrays, including the one which 'test' was contained in.

Could a Binary Search be used here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit first, do you want to search through all arrays, and when you find the first instance of 'test' then print out that index of all arrays?

Comment: I want to search through one array and then when it finds 'test' prints out the index of all arrays.

Comment: create a method that takes an `int i` and prints out `a[i]` and `b[i]` etc. What are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. An array has elements which may be strings, but not "lines of strings". Each elemnt of an array has an index. Probably array1[22] == "test". What do you mean by "view"? If you already know the index you could just print array2[22] and array3[22] (plus some error checking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Simply iterate through the first array until you find the string you are looking for, then use the counter to access the remaining arrays. Your code should look something like this:

```
 for (int counter = 0; counter < Array1.Length; counter++)
 {
     if (Array1[counter] == "your string here")
     {
         //Print same line on remaining arrays, eg:
         Console.WriteLine(Array2[counter]);
         Console.WriteLine(Array3[counter]);
         //Then you can break out of the loop
         break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If those are arrays, i can't see any problem doing this:

```
string[] array1, array2, array3..// etc
...
var stringToSearch = "someValue";
... 
int matchPosition = Array.IndexOf(array1, stringToSearch);

if(matchPosition != -1)
{
     // just sample of usage - access string by array2[matchPosition]
     Console.WriteLine(array2[matchPosition]);
     Console.WriteLine(array3[matchPosition]);
}
```